# How would I prevent a random function from choosing the last outcome of that function when run another time?

Tags: javascript

I have a function choosing a random item from an array. I'm trying to figure out how I can run this function so that the next time it is run, it excludes the previous choice as to not repeat choices.

```
var itemArray= [
    {
        name: 'Apple'
    },
    {
        name: 'Orange'
    },
    {
        name: 'Banana'
    }
];

var itemLength = itemArray.length;

var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * legendLength) + 0;
var randomPick = itemArray[randomNumber];

document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = '<b>' + randomPick.name;
```

I'm sure this is a simple fix I just can't seem to work it out. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You can simply safe that random number outside of your function. Then run the new random number until it's not the same. You can also save the last X numbers into an array and keep them from popping up again

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to "remember" the last result, you can do something like this:

```
var itemArray= [
{
    name: 'Apple'
},
{
    name: 'Orange'
},
{
    name: 'Banana'
}
];

var itemLength = itemArray.length;

var randomNumber = ""
var oldNumber = 1

function getRandomNumber(){
do{
    randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * itemLength) + 0;
}
while(randomNumber === oldNumber)

oldNumber = randomNumber
var randomPick = itemArray[randomNumber];

document.getElementById("item").innerHTML = '<b>' + randomPick.name;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code here will work, when it runs out of items it will return undefined by default.

```
var itemArray= [
    {name: 'Apple'},
    {name: 'Orange'},
    {name: 'Banana'},
    {name: 'Pineapple'},
    {name: 'Avocado'},
    {name: 'Kiwi'}
];
var selectedItems = []

function getRandomItem(array) {
    let difference = array.filter(x => !selectedItems.includes(x));
    var itemLength = difference.length;
    var randomNumber = Math.floor(Math.random() * itemLength) + 0;
    var randomPick = difference[randomNumber];
    selectedItems.push(randomPick)
    return randomPick
}
```

The function basically removes elements that have been used from original array and then picks from that new array which doesn't have already picked items.